# Run different jobs with different triggers

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm updating the workflow file of my GitHub Actions for my current project and, if possible, I want to have different triggers for each job. More specifically, I want the `tests` job to be run on `push`, while the `build` job should be run on `workflow_dispatch` (so that I don't have to the cache every month, since currently each build of the project has ~200Mb). How can I do that?

Here's a simplified version of my current workflow file:

```yaml
name: Tests + Build 

on: push

jobs:
  tests:
    name: Test my project 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        unityVersion:
          - 2021.3.4f1
    steps:
      # Checkout (without LFS)

      # Git LFS

      # Cache

      # Run Unity Test (Editor and Play mode)

  build:
    name: Build my project ✨
    needs: tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        unityVersion:
          - 2021.3.4f1
    steps:
      # Checkout (without LFS)

      # Git LFS

      # Cache

      # Build

      # Output
```

Comment: Move the build job to a _separate_ workflow file, with whatever triggers it needs?

Comment: You can use separate files, or you can use an `if` clause on each job, like `if: github.event_name == 'push'`, but at that point, why have the jobs in the same file to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

```
name: Tests + Build 

on: push

workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      build:
        type: choice
        description: build without cache
        options:
          - 'true'
          - 'false'

jobs:
  tests:
    name: Test my project 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        unityVersion:
          - 2021.3.4f1
    steps:
      # Checkout (without LFS)

      # Git LFS

      # Cache

      # Run Unity Test (Editor and Play mode)

  build:
    name: Build my project ✨
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
if: (github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch' && github.event.inputs.build == 'true')
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        unityVersion:
          - 2021.3.4f1
    steps:
      # Checkout (without LFS)

      # Git LFS

      # Cache

      # Build

      # Output
```